# Create a Groupedby HTML table using linq query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

Using the following:  Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013, VB, Bootstrap, Jquery

I am new to web design.

I am trying to create a list/table...anything...to show a list of Equipment that is Grouped by their Department.  I currently just have the Department listed.  There are 4 records in the table:
Two records are in Department 01 and Two are in Department 02
There are two equipment in each department.
The code below is pulling in all the records creating a multiple list of same department:

```
 - 01
 - 01
 - 02
 - 02
```

I would like to have:

```
 - 01
 - Equipment1
 - Equipment2
 - 02
 - Equipment1
 - Equipment2
```

The line:

```
mUserHistorys = mUserHistorys.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Department_Selected).ToList()
```

is where I am pulling in from data in memory which is loaded when the page is loaded.
How do I get unique Departments?  I've tried Distinct and GroupBy but I don't believe I'm placing them correctly.

```
Private Sub RenderPage()

Dim HTMLString As String = ""
Dim SortKey As String = "A"
Dim CompareValue As String = ""
Dim SubmitString = ""

mUserHistorys = mUserHistorys.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Department_Selected).ToList()
For Each p In mUserHistorys
    SubmitString = "Bookmark:" & p.Department_Selected & "-" & p.Equipment_Selected

    HTMLString &= "<table> " & vbCrLf
    HTMLString &= "<td>" & p.Department_Selected & "</td>" & vbCrLf
    HTMLString &= "</table> " & vbCrLf       

Next
Me.literalListHTML.Text = HTMLString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var info = (from b in mUserHistorys
                        where b.Department_Selected != null
                        select b).ToList()
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Department_Selected)
                        .Select(y => y.First())
                        .OrderBy(z => z.Department_Selected);
```

I have had luck using this linq query for something similar. If it is already a List of objects you can start at the .GroupBy i.e

```
mUserHistorys.GroupBy(x => x.Department_Selected)
                        .Select(y => y.First())
                        .OrderBy(z => z.Department_Selected);
```

Comment: I've tried both and they have flags on the x, y and z.  They state: x is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: I have tested a sample code. Apologies for my VB code style I am unfamiliar with VB.NET compared to C#. 

 [.NetFiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BD9TH9).

Answer (score 0):

@stuggyg
This what I ended up with that is working.  My only issue now is that the Equipment are not ascending.  But, thank you very much for your help!  It helped me come up with this code:

```
    Private Sub RenderPage()

    Dim HTMLString As String = ""
    Dim SortKey As String = "A"
    Dim CompareValue As String = ""
    Dim SubmitString = ""

    Dim Depts = From dept In mUserHistorys
                Select dept.User_ID, dept.Department_Selected, dept.Equipment_Selected
                Where User_ID = _user.User_ID
                Order By Equipment_Selected Ascending
                Group By DeptName = Department_Selected
                Into EqInDept = Group
                Order By DeptName

    HTMLString &= "<div class=""container-float""> " & vbCrLf
    For Each p In Depts
        HTMLString &= "<a id=""deptheader"" class=""list-group-item"">" & p.DeptName & "" & vbCrLf

        For Each r In mUserHistorys
            SubmitString = "Bookmark:" & r.Department_Selected & "-" & r.Equipment_Selected
            If r.Department_Selected = p.DeptName Then
                HTMLString &= "<a id=""equiplist"" class=""list-group-item"" <button id=""iconButton"" onclick=""SubmitNextForm('" & SubmitString & "');""  type=""button"" class=""btn btn-normal""><span class=""glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"" ></span></button>" & r.Equipment_Selected & "</a>" & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
        HTMLString &= "</a> " & vbCrLf
    Next
    HTMLString &= "</div> " & vbCrLf

    Me.literalListHTML.Text = HTMLString
End Sub
```